Html2Pdf library is adding extra spacing on page-break
When I use the class .break-page, the extra space above the table is added (highlighted in red). I have tried using negative margin values, but it does not work.
I want the table to move to the top of the new page when I apply .break-page and remove the extra spacing that is being applied on the table. What can be the possible solution?
The code snippet of the function being called,
function downloadPdf(
  pdfName?: string,
  param?: string,
  htmlElement?: ElementRef
): void {

  let opt = {
    margin: [4, 3, 2, 3],
    filename: pdfName + "_" + param + ".pdf",
    image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 1 },
    html2canvas: { scale: 2, width: 1100 },
    pagebreak: { mode: "css", before: ".break-page" },
    jsPDF: { unit: "em", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
  };

  html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(htmlElement.nativeElement.innerHTML)
    .toContainer()
    .save();
}



Added, thank you James Ashok for helping
